# Material-UI: Overriding style classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx, styled-components

I was trying to follow the [MUI guide on overriding MUI styles](https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides), but using *styled-components* instead of *JSS*. In particular, I could not get the first two approaches to work:

1. Using `className`
2. Using `classes`

I have made sure the injection order in head is correct, so that is not the issue. My problem is that the classes I need are not added to the DOM.

Also note: I managed to get normal *styled-components* to work well with *MUI*. I.e. the following works fine:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { darken, fade } from '@material-ui/core/styles/colorManipulator';

const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  color: ${props => props.theme.palette.primary.contrastText };
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #fe6b8b 30%, #ff8e53 90%);
  border-radius: ${props => props.theme.shape.borderRadius}px;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, 0.3);
  &:hover {
    background: ${props => {
      return `linear-gradient(45deg, ${darken(`#fe6b8b`, 0.2)} 30%, ${darken(`#ff8e53`, 0.2)} 90%)`;
    }};
  };
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  ${props => props.theme.breakpoints.up('md')} {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
`;

// In render: 
<StyledButton>Hello World</StyledButton>
```

The following however, does not work:

```
styled(Typography)`
  &.my-class {
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
  }
`;

// In render:
<Typography className="my-class" component="h2" variant="h2">
```

Dev Tools does show that `my-class` is indeed added, but, the class does not get added to the DOM. I followed [this guide](https://gist.github.com/Danilo-Araujo-Silva/2ce11fd0540dcc7eb3ad3e67fd75d02a) (Third Method).

Any idea why?

*PS: I do not want to turn Typography into a StyledTypography component. I know that works (see first example above). Instead, I want to follow the override guide in the MUI docs.*

**Edit**

Relevant installed packages:

- "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.3"
- "styled-components": "^4.2.0",

**Edit 2:**

I got it to work if I import an external style sheet:

```
// style.css
.my-class2 {
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

// index.js
import React from 'react';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import './style.css';

const IndexPage = () => (
  <>
    <Typography className="my-class2" component="h2" variant="h2">
      Testing h2 (MUI)
    </Typography>
  </>
);

<Typography className="my-class2" component="h2" variant="h2">
  Testing h2 (MUI)
</Typography>
```

However, I would like to keep it all inside the component.

**Thus, my problem boils down to:**

How can I add locally scoped styles to the DOM from within a component, without for instance creating a new component tag / variable with *styled-components*?

Comment: I'll look this over in a moment and see if I can help. I found myself in this particular pit of despair not too long ago so I can commiserate. The documentation is good, but somehow it is simply just not clear enough when it comes to their style overrides, especially when there's multiple ways to do it. Could you please provide your version of MUI in the question text/ what subdirectories you have installed? a.e. `/core`, `/icons`, etc.

Comment: Apologies, I am having a hard time getting it to work as well. I'll give it a crack again later on, and I'll watch this question because I'm curious what the solution is right now. Here's a sandbox template for anyone else interested in trying to answer: https://codesandbox.io/s/j2wnp39m6y

Comment: @zfrisch I think it will work fine if you import the CSS style sheet the way you did. Because the CSS classes are then added to the DOM. But, I was wondering if there was a way to do it within the component itself (without converting the MUI component to a styled component, or using JSS HOC like in the MUI docs).

Comment: Ah - I didn't actually do that intentionally. I simply loaded your dependencies into a react template that already had that stylesheet baked in, so it wasn't offered as a solution to your issue.

Comment: I don't think the guide you linked to was meant to show anything different than what you know already works. It just left out setting the result into a variable (or exporting the result so it could be imported for use in a different file). I don't think it was trying to indicate that you could override the default AppBar styles that way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @RyanCogswell . What made me think otherwise, was that the  author wrote the component not with a styled component tag. In other words, he used `AppData`, as opposed to for instance `StyledAppData`. This led me to believe that there was another way to add the class to the dom, using `styled` without setting it to any variable. I.e. that such a syntax would add the class straight to the DOM.